# method vs property What is faster?

Tags: python, class, methods, beautifulsoup, properties

In `bs4.BeautifulSoup`, there is `bs4.element.Tag` object. 
It have property `text`
and it have method `get_text`.
Both are return same result about `text(str).`

And I got a curiosity about

> " method vs property "

Which access is faster?

I check on my local by `time.time()`, but in every run, results are changed.

Is this a useless curiosity?

Comment: `time.time()` results will be different at different runs. But the difference is not too much is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text` attribute can only give the text as it is.

Whereas [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) can do some 'customization'. Like inserting a separator in between the text of different tags or stripping the white spaces from the ends of the strings.

---

`get_text()` accepts the following parameters:

- `separator`: Insert a string as separator between the texts of the individual tags.
- `strip`: Strip the ends of the tags' texts of white spaces.

Consider

```
html_str = """
<div>
\nHello
  <span>World!</span>
  <a href="">Click here</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'html.parser')
```

If we consider the `<div>` tag's text like

```
soup.text
```

it would be

```
'\n\n\nHello\n  World!\nClick here\n\n'
```

If `strip` argument is used

```
>>> soup.get_text(strip=True)
'HelloWorld!Click here'
```

If `separator` argument is used

```
>>> soup.get_text(separator='**')
'\n**\n\nHello\n  **World!**\n**Click here**\n**\n'
```

If both `separator` and `strip` are used

```
>>> soup.get_text(separator='**', strip=True)
'Hello**World!**Click here'
```

---

Running time seems to be roughly the same.

```
%timeit soup.text
4.16 µs ± 56.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit soup.get_text(strip=True)
5.38 µs ± 154 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit soup.get_text(separator='**')
4.16 µs ± 53.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit soup.get_text(separator='**', strip=True)
5.45 µs ± 213 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```